# Change primary key for one page

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to change the primary key in the table (model) for just one page.

In the initialize if I change the primary key and display field to `type` it works, but the rest of my pages that I have made that uses `id` as the primary key and display field do not. I need to change it depending on what page it is on. I've tried using

```
$billingi = $this->Billing->get($invoice, [
            'contain' => ['Items'],
            'primaryKey' => 'type',
            'displayField' => 'type'
        ]);
```

And as I figured, it didn't work. Is there any way to change it for just one page?

Comment: What version of cake are you using?

Comment: Cakephp 3. I eventually just used a different model, although I'm not sure if that is the best approach. `$this->loadModel('modelName');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually decided to load a different model using

```
$this->loadModel('modelname');
```

This allowed me to set a different primaryKey and displayField to accomplish my goal.